# Recover data off internal memory of a pin-locked phone?

Tags: internal-storage

How to retrieve data off of internal memory for LG Optimus (android 2.3.4), not rooted, locked via PIN password, and no forgot password showing up on PIN entry screen?  I'm more particularly interested in contact data then anything else.

Comment: A good point would be disabling the lock. There's e.g. an app you can install via the Playstore WebIF which does this. See: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Using `adb`, you can use `adb pull` to take any file you want from your phone, event if it is protected and locked (I tried on 4.1.2, don't know if it works on more up to date versions).

Only the `/data` folder needs `root` privileges to be read and it is where your contacts are stored. If you have `root` privileges, you can look at [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41459/16437) to know where you can find them.

*Note that you have to enable **USB debugging** before trying these steps.*

Answer (score 0):

Why is there no "Forgot PIN" or a Mail recovery option there? :(

See if this app is compatible and use it:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.thomascannon.screenlockbypass.pro

If you have your contacts synced on your Google account, they will automatically get restored.

This might help you get the data back:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCommandLine/article.html#adb_copy