# Lost Contacts after 5.0.1 update

Tags: contacts

After updating to 5.0.1, I had bad problems with wifi connections. After trying every possible solution without success, I decided to do a backup and reset. First though, I copied both the card and phone folders to my laptop.
After the reset, the wifi problem seems to be fixed, but now all the contacts are gone. For whatever reason, they were not synced with my google account.
Can I find the contct data somewhere in the folders that I copied onto my laptop?
Thanks in advance for any help.
Simon

Samsung S4

Comment: What where you running before?

Comment: Android4.2 I think... The contacts were still there after the upgrade, they disappeared after the backup-reset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post is useful for you: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41459/31639

Basically you could try searching the sqlite database location under `/data/data`
By default it's `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases` (at least for me (currently running GPE on my GS4))

Anyway, just copying some folders from internal storage is far away from a correct way of backing up contacts etc. and if your contacts would be stored in your Google account they would've been automatically imported again after relinking your Google account to your device.

If you gained back access to your contacts you should check the correct storage of your them and move them to your Google account if necessary.

Comment: thx for the answer. Im not a phone tech, and was basically just following instructions from an android help website. (not this one). I cant understand why the google account didn't sync the contacts, but they definitely are not there. BVut logically, I would have have thought that the contacts are stored as data somewhrer on the phone, as you can still access them with no internet.