# Can't find call log from adb shell

Tags: adb, logging, command-line, call-history, telephony

Phone is a Samsung Galaxy E5 SM-E500m (lte, dual chip, codename `e5lte`). Android version `5.1.1 "lollipop"` Stock ROM.

I pulled the database file from `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db` and tried to inspect it with both the [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and also the [`sqlite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) command-line tool.

The file is 1.7MiB in size. It has 42 tables.

From my research efforts, I was hoping to be able to see the call log in the `calls` table; but it is empty (0 records).
Other tables in this db file all appear to have data.

I also checked the file over `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db` but it does not appear to contain call logs (only 4 tables: `android_metadata`, `carriers`, `siminfo` and `sqlite_sequence`).

Where else can I potentially find the call logs for this device?

The call log is shown correctly in the Phone app.

Thank you.

Comment: `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/calllog.db`

Comment: @IrfanLatif it's not there. I only got `contacts2.db` and `profile.db`.

Comment: In fact `find . -type f -name "calllog.db"` shows me such a file does not exist anywhere under `/data/data/`.

Comment: Ok then it was added later, exists on Pie. Don't have a lollipop device to help you exactly. May be some extra column in some table of `contacts2.db` or `telephony.db`. A trick is to use `inotify` to watch for changed files when you make a call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41455/where-is-the-data-for-contacts-storage-located