# Notes and Contacts Recovery (Huawei P6 Android 4.4)

Tags: contacts, data-recovery, notes

I have a Huawei Ascend P6 with 4.4 Android sutcking on the start up logo. I have many important notes (saved by default notepad app) and some unsynched contacts in there. so I have access to the location of them (if it is correct: `/data/data/com.example.android.notes/com.android.contacts/com.android.provides.contacts`) using aroma file manager. the rom I installed is root and has TWRP recovery so I copied those folder. I was wonder will they be back if I replace the mentioned files after flashing a new rom?

Comment: Fort the contacts please see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41459/2241). It contains also a description to check/view the extracted database. In general I would recommend to not only save the files selective, but as you have the possibility via TWRP to make a full backup. If you save data of apps separately make sure to `tar´ them as this includes the Linux access permissions. You can practice data recovery using a rooted Android 4.4 emulator, e.g. Genymotion.